# jquery -how to measure height of element with display:none?

Tags: jquery, height

If I have an element set to *display:none*.

Firebug tells me the element has:
 *margin-top/bottom: 20px*
 *padding-top/bottom: 20px*
*height: -22px*

If the element is set to  *display:block* height changes to this:

*height: 73px*

I need to retrieve the -22px via Jquery, but I'm always getting the 73px no matter what display is set to. Is there a way to get the -22px?

Thanks!

Comment: It's firebug thingy that it displays its height minus.

Comment: still my positioning is off by 22px. Never mind the minus, I need to get the 22px to adjust my overall positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use jQuery. If you have the element (maybe with `getElementById()`), just get its `offsetHeight`. That should be `0px` - there's no such thing as negative height, I think that's just Firebug taking the offsetHeight and subtracting margin/border/padding...

I'm almost certain that jQuery will assume you want the actual height when visible, so it'll do something like "make it visible, get the height, make it invisible again".

Comment: the strange thing is, the element I'm trying to position is exactly off by -22px. So I figured maybe it's because of this div with _display:none_ and _height:-22px_.

Comment: offsetHeight made my day. Thanks!

Comment: See, this is why I am against jQuery et al. When you write your own code, it's a lot easier to get it to do *exactly* what you want it to do.

Comment: agree, but kind of hard when you need to change a plugin :-)

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around and, IMHO, the problem lies within the actual div. Do some further investigation.

```
<div id='testDiv' style='padding:20px; margin:20px; display:none; border:1px solid red; ' ></div>

alert($('#testDiv').height());          // 0
alert($('#testDiv').innerHeight());     //40
alert($('#testDiv').outerHeight());     //42  <=======

$('#testDiv').css('display','block');

alert($('#testDiv').height());          // 0
alert($('#testDiv').innerHeight());     //40
alert($('#testDiv').outerHeight());     //42  <========
```